# xcodebuild does not recognize provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, react-native, command-line-interface, provisioning-profile, xcodebuild

I am trying to build and publish a react native iOS app on Testflight through the Xcode CLI. I manage to build and publish the application through Xcode GUI, but I cannot do the same using Xcode CLI. After the archive is created with xcodebuild, I'm getting an error for provisioning profiles even though I've checked that they've all been installed and already exist. I am using MacBook Pro PC, macOS Ventura 13.1 and Xcode 14.2.

ERROR:

```
Error Domain=IDEProfileLocatorErrorDomain Code=4 "No "iOS App Store" profiles for team 'xxxxxxxxxx' matching 'test-profile' are installed." UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, NSLocalizedDescription=No "iOS App Store" profiles for team 'xxxxxxxxxx' matching 'test-profile' are installed., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Install a profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or specify a different profile in your Export Options property list.}
```

I use the sample app [https://github.com/croma-app/croma]), which I successfully built through Xcode 14.2, and then created an archive, which I can export as an .ipa file or upload to Testflight directly. Xcode succeeds in signing and exporting the archive, while the xcodebuild CLI fails.

xcodebuild command:

```
user@SPARE-WSM-xxxxxxxxxxxx ios % sudo xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist ExportOptions.plist -archivePath croma.xcarchive -exportPath '/ipa/'
```

- I double checked that the ExportOptions.plist is identical to the archive created by Xcode.
- Xcode recognizes the iOS App Store distribution "test-profile" while xcodebuild does not.
- "test-profile" is installed and located at '/Users/user/Library/MobileDevices/Provisioning Profiles/f5de3135-6ffa-4834-9f61-be39a178e284.mobileprovision'.
- Also, inside the ExportOptions.plist file I used the UUID "f5de3135-6ffa-4834-9f61-be39a178e284" and "f5de3135-6ffa-4834-9f61-be39a178e284.mobileprovision'" instead of the name "test-profile".
- Automatically manage signing did not help, xcodebuild CLI still does not recognize the profile.
- Downgrading Xcode version to 14.1 didn't help either.
  -I also tried unlocking the keychain although using sudo, but the error is still the same.

```
security unlock-keychain -p 'xxxxxxxx' /Users/user/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
```

I believe that it is a small problem with the user's permissions and his access to provisioning profiles files. But how can I fix it?

- How can I verify that 'Library/MobileDevices/Provisioning Profiles/' is the correct location where xcodebuild is looking for provisioning profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

After I started the xcodebuild archive command without "sudo", I realized that I was getting some other error. I was able to solve that error, as well as others, because I was getting a clearer error message. In the end I was able to archive and upload the app to Testflight through the xcodebuild CLI.

I tried the same process once again using "sudo", but I still get the same error. I think xcodebuild does not work as expected when using "sudo". Since I spent a lot of time trying to figure out the cause of the problem, I would suggest avoiding using "sudo" in this case.

Comment: Awesome. Good to know you figured it out. And thanks for sharing as-well.

Comment: Hi @devops, I got similar issue and have tried multiple solution. Could you share how you fix this? Thanks a lot before

Answer (score 0):

When archiving using xcode, there must be a scheme selected in xcode. Can you try specifying the scheme as part of the xcodebuild command. Also, if you're using cocoapods by any chance, you should also specify the workspace.

These can be done via the `-scheme` and `-workspace` command parameters respectively.

If this helps you, please consider marking this as the answer.

Also, 'Library/MobileDevices/Provisioning Profiles/' is indeed the correct location where the provisioning profile should be stored.
And you do not need to add the '.provisioning' extension in the ExportOptions.plist file.

Comment: Archive is already created with xcodebuild:
sudo xcodebuild archive -workspace croma.xcworkspace -scheme croma -configuration Release -archivePath croma.xcarchive -destination='generic/platform=iOS'.

Comment: OK. Instead of `destination='generic/platform=iOS'` (remove this), could you use `-sdk iphoneos` (add this) parameter and let me know the outcome?
Also, you are specifying configuration here, so could you validate using xcode scheme editor that the archive setting in that scheme uses the release configuration.
Just dotting our 'I's and crossing our 'T's here :), if this doesn't help please let me know I'll give it more thought.
This is based on the build script that I've written for one of my own apps and has been working for a very long time.

Comment: Also, could you test by adding the `clean` parameter to the command please (alongside the above suggestions).

Comment: Essentially I feel there's something missing with the command parameters because archiving with xcode works, which means that you've got everything set up, we just need to specify the correct parameters for the command.

Comment: I did everything you mentioned, same error. I even tried with another application, first through xcode build, run, archive and then publish to testflight, everything went successfully. But xcodebuild still doesn't recognize provisioning profiles...

Comment: It must be something with react-native or provisioning profiles files permissions...

Comment: OK. Try this, download your provisioning profile from Apple Dev portal, delete all provisioning profiles from your Library folder (ensure you can download all of these later to be safe). Then open your project in xcode, go to project settings, select your target, go to the signing and distribution tab, then for all your schemes, click the provisioning profile drop-down there, select import, and then select the file downloaded from appstore. Now use the provisioning profile name that appears in the dropdown in your ExportOptions.plist. Let me know if you're able to test this.

Comment: I followed your instructions even before you wrote them, but using "sudo" I get the same error. Thank you for the tips, they helped me figure out what could be causing the problem, which I think is the "sudo" I used in the xcodebuild commands